# Contact form 7 ... about not all fields getting sent

Tags: windows-7, contacts, forms

I ran across a similar topic being discussed. But the solution was specific to that particular case without any mention of the principles behind it...

my 'contact form 7' form tab looks like this:

```
<label> Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Phone
    [tel Phone] </label>

<label> Wedding Date
     [date Wedding Date] </label>

 </label> Where did you find us?
         [text Where did you find us?]

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]
```

Mail tab like this:

```
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]
```

So obviously I'm not getting all the fields sent to my email. Could someone with an understanding of the code tell me how to translate my *form* tab into what I need to put in the *mail* tab?

Answer (score 0):

First, the forms need to use single-words or strings as the field name. This ensures that you have a field to capture.

```
 <label> Name (required)
     [text* your-name] </label>

 <label> Email (required)
     [email* your-email] </label>

 <label> Phone
     [tel Phone] </label>

 <label> Wedding Date
     [date Wedding-Date] </label>

 <label> Where did you find us?
     [text source] </label>

 <label> Your Message
     [textarea your-message] </label>

 [submit "Send"]
```

Then the fields in the form need to be added to the email:

```
 From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
 Subject: [your-subject]

 Date: [Wedding-Date]
 Phone: [Phone]
 Source: [source]

 Message Body:
 [your-message]
```